# Android MonoGame game won`t start on phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, monogame

I learning Xamarin and MonoGame for Android. I have one problem. On emulator of Android 9 game starts normally. On a real phone, the game won't start. I test on phones with Android 10 and Android 11. I set all Android API versions, but this does not help.
[Android 11 phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0f7A.jpg)
[Android 10 phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXvUa.jpg)

***Code of file "Game1.cs":***

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;

namespace AndroidTest
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
        private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

        private SpriteFont font;
        private Vector2 position;

        private float x, y;

        public Game1()
        {
            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
            position = new Vector2(10, 10);

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            font = this.Content.Load<SpriteFont>("File");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            TouchCollection tc = TouchPanel.GetState();
            foreach (TouchLocation tl in tc)
            {
                position = tl.Position;
                x = tl.Position.X;
                y = tl.Position.Y;
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            _spriteBatch.Begin();
            _spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "This is test!", position, Color.GreenYellow);
            _spriteBatch.DrawString(font, string.Format("X:{0} Y:{1}", x, y), new Vector2(10, 1635), Color.Beige);
            _spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

***Code of file "AndroidManifest.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="AndroidTest.AndroidTest" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="30" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_FORMAT_FILESYSTEMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
    <application android:label="AndroidTest"></application>
</manifest>
```

***Code of file "Activity1.cs"***

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace AndroidTest
{
    [Activity(
        Label = "@string/app_name",
        MainLauncher = true,
        Icon = "@drawable/icon",
        AlwaysRetainTaskState = true,
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleInstance,
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.FullUser,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
    )]
    public class Activity1 : AndroidGameActivity
    {
        private Game1 _game;
        private View _view;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            _game = new Game1();
            _view = _game.Services.GetService(typeof(View)) as View;

            SetContentView(_view);
            _game.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do the logs show?

Comment: but how to see that logs on my phones??

Comment: @oleg002 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows

Comment: What is the android version of the real phone in which your game is not working?

Comment: My game stucks on all versions of Android (10 and 11).

Comment: You could make a breakpoint to see if the _view is null in the OnCreate method.